# Rerender deletes the data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have made a component named wholeCard in which there are several components like 3-Inputs, button, dropdown
and, i have also made an add button outside the whole card.

The problem is, when i click on the add button, the data in every wholecard component gets disappeared. I know it is because it is re-rendering the component, but how can i stop the data to disappear?

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

function added(boo) {
    boo.preventDefault();
    setValue(value + 1);
}

<>
{[...Array(value)].map((e, position) => {
  return ( <WholeCard key={position} }} /> ); })}
  <button onClick={added}>Add!</button>
</>
```

please help

Comment: You should also store the state of each `WholeCard` in the parent.

Comment: how can i do that? can you explain a bit more, i am beginner in react.

Comment: What does each `WholeCard` contain? add its code. And from what I understand you're trying to render as many `WholeCard` components as the `value`, is that correct?

Comment: each wholeCard has inputs, some buttons, dropdown.
and yes, i am trying to render as many wholecard same as value.

Comment: In the parent's state add an array and each element of that array can be an object which has the values entered in the `WholeCard` component and when rendering the list pass on the values as props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xekuba?file=index.js) which does what you're asking. Go through the code of `index.js` and you'll understand how you can implement the same in your app.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cards: [
        {
          value: 'something',
          id: 'some id'
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  addCardHandler = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      cards: prevState.cards.concat({
        value: '',
        id: Math.random()
      })
    }));
  };
  changeHandler = (e, id) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const updatedCards = [...prevState.cards];
      const reqCardIndex = updatedCards.findIndex(card => card.id === id);
      const reqCard = updatedCards[reqCardIndex];
      reqCard.value = value;
      return {
        cards: updatedCards
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          {this.state.cards.map(el => (
            <Card
              key={el.id}
              {...el}
              changed={() => this.changeHandler(event, el.id)}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.addCardHandler}>Add</button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hi Ramesh, i got your code, except 1 line in changeHandler function
` return {
     cards: updatedCards
      };`
what this line means? and how can i write this in hooks?

Comment: @Prabhatkumar - You can pass a function to `setState` and update the state, we do this when the new state depends on the old state. Coming to hooks you can use `useState` hook in the same way.